# How to get only not joined (excluded) documents between two collections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

The problem is around two collections Users and Forms. Each user is joined with his form by Id.So every form in a Forms collection has a userId foreign key.
I need to get all documents from a Users collection , which doesn't have any form connected to it (there is no such a form).
In SQL I would do something like this:
SELECT * 
FROM Users U
LEFT JOIN Forms F
ON U._id= F.userId 
WHERE F.userId IS NULL

U=A , F=B
[image: diagram]

How can we achieve this functionality in MongoDb , may be with Mongoose on a nodeJs side? I couldn't find any solution based on a $lookup aggregation.

Schemas:
*employeeId is a reference to Users _id

```
let FormsSchema = new Schema({
employeeId:{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref:'User'
},
companyId:{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId
},
formData : {
    type:String
},
formType : {
    type:String
},
formDate :{
    type:Date,default: Date.now
},
formState: {
    type: String, required: true, enum: ["new","draft","aproved","pendingHR","pendingEMP","pendingSigned"], default: "new"
},
messageData : {
    type:Schema.Types.Mixed
},
formIdkunDate:{
    type:Date,default: Date.now
},
attachmentDirty:{
    type:Boolean
},
company : {
    type:Schema.Types.Mixed
},
formShnatMas : {
    type:String
},
sendDate : {
    type:Date,default: Date.now
},
draftDate : {
    type:Date,default: Date.now
},
fixDate : {
    type:Date,default: Date.now
},
is101FormOpenedAfterArchive : {
    type:Boolean
},
```

}

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
userName:{
    type:String,
    trim:true
},
CreateDate :{
    type:Date,default: Date.now 
},
UpdateDate :{
    type:Date,default: Date.now
},
password : {
    type:String,
    required: true,
    trim:true
},
isFirstEntrance : {
    type:Boolean
},
resetToken : {
    type:String
},
resetPasswordExpires : {
    type:String
},
resetOtpPassExpires : {
    type:String
},
otpPass : {
    type:String,
    trim:true
},
userType: {
    type: String, required: true, enum: ["employee","hr","admin"], default: "employee"
} ,
employeeData : {
    type:Schema.Types.Mixed
},
partnerData : {
    type:Schema.Types.Mixed
},
externalId : {
    type:String
},
isChangedFromPrevious : {
    type:Boolean
},
isFirstYearWorker101 : {
    type:Boolean
},
lastLogin :{
    type:Number
},
loginAttempts : {
    type:Number
},
```

});

Comment: can you please share schema of user and form ?

Comment: I updated the question. Shared schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the schema given by you and I am able to get all documents from a Users collection , which doesn't have any form connected to it using `$lookup`. Please use below aggregate query

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup:{
        "localField": "_id",
        "from": "form",
        "foreignField": "employeeId",
        "as": "forminfo"
    }
  },{
    $match:{
        forminfo: {$size: 0}
    }
  }
])
```